# I am struggling to display these variables from this function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am new react and I am trying to display the arrayofData and arrayofID but I am not sure how to do it?

```
class ListCampaigns extends React.Component {
  FindDocuments() {
    db.collection("campaigns")
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        var arrayofID = [];
        var arrayofData = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          arrayofID.push(doc.id);
          const campaignName = doc.data();
          arrayofData.push(campaignName);
        });

        return arrayofData, arrayofID;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{this.FindDocuments}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use APIs in React with Asynchronous calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329481/how-to-use-apis-in-react-with-asynchronous-calls)

Comment: You need a solid understanding of how state works in React, especially with relation to async calls to your api. This question should have what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329481/how-to-use-apis-in-react-with-asynchronous-calls

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to render a function in the render method by writing `this.FindDocuments`. You could instead use the `componentDidMount` hook and call `this.FindDocuments()` and set the data you get in response in the component state.

**Example**

```
class ListCampaigns extends React.Component {
  state = { documents: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.findDocuments();
  }   

  findDocuments = () => {
    db.collection("campaigns")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        var data = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          data.push({
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data()
          });
        });

        this.setState({ documents: data });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.documents.map(document => (
            <li key={document.id}>{document.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```